# predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stats'

Tags: python, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I am trying to get predictions from a Tensor Flow custom routine served on AI platform.

I have managed to serve it with the following settings: --runtime-version 2.3 --python-version 3.7 --machine-type mls1-c4-m2

But I keep getting this error when i try to make any predictions.

```
ERROR:root:Prediction failed: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stats'
ERROR:root:Prediction failed: unknown error.
```

The routine has two steps:

1. Takes the input (a string) and transforms it into a embedding using a bow model in .pkl format
2. Uses the embeddings for getting the predictions using a keras model saved as an .h5 file

this is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Keras==2.3.1', 'sklearn==0.0', 'h5py<3.0.0', 'numpy==1.16.0', 'scipy==1.4.1', 'pyyaml==5.2']

setup(
        name='my_custom_code',
        version='0.1',
        scripts=['predictor.py'],
        install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
        packages=find_packages(),
        include_package_data=False,
        description=''
)
```

And this is my predictor.py

```
import os
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MyPredictor(object):

    def __init__(self, model, bow_model):
        self._model = model
        self._bow_model = bow_model

    def predict(self, instances):

        outputs = []

        for x in instances:
            vector = self.embedding(x)
            output = self._model.predict(vector)
            outputs.append(output)

        return outputs

    def embedding(self, statement):
        vector = self._bow_model.transform(statement).toarray()
        vector = vector.to_list()
        return vector


    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):

        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.h5')
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile = False)

        preprocessor_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'bow.pkl')
        with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
            bow_model = pickle.load(f)

        return cls(model, bow_model)
```

The script im using for testing is:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

instances = ['test','test']]

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
name = 'projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_NAME, VERSION_NAME)

response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': instances}
).execute()

if 'error' in response:
    raise RuntimeError(response['error'])
else:
  print(response['predictions'])
```

Comment: According to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#predictor-class) the predictor method should be used like `def predict(self, instances, **kwargs)`. Was it helpful?

Comment: Glad to hear, I've composed the answer in order to finalize this case. If you get this answer as solution one, you can consider [accept/up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the *Custom prediction routine* [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines), once creating the predictor [class](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#predictor-class), `predict()` method should be supplied with `self, instances, **kwargs` arguments to properly handle the prediction request.

> instances: A list of prediction input instances.

> **kwargs: A dictionary of keyword args provided as additional fields on the predict request body.